# Where should the "developed/designed/ by ..." information go in a website?

Tags: website-design, web

I am a freelancer, and currently designing the website for a startup. I was wondering if there are any guidelines which talk about incorporation of the designer's information in the website.

On which page/section should, if at all, the "designed by X firm" be displayed?

For that matter, how to best display "attributed to .." information, if using multiple assets?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not a UX question, it seems to be more related to designing your site. Start by looking at their company's design guidelines (if they have those already). In general, it's quite common to put it in the lower-right corner (doesn't mean it's prohibited from putting it somewhere else...). Putting it on each page makes sense if you want people to find the "creator". I also use it to figure out how outdated a site is, e.g. (c) 2008 ...

Comment: Agreed with @Xabre, not really a UX question this is more of a design question.

Comment: Most professional sites do not show this info. If you're donating your time to help a project, then typically the footer near the copyright info.

Comment: [humans.txt](http://humanstxt.org/)

Comment: After thinking about this, I disagree with the comments, this is a question with several UX implications (I voted to close it, sadly can't roll back)

Comment: @thunderblaster this is the first time I've heard about humans.txt. Insightful read. You might want to consider summarizing this and putting it up as an answer.

Comment: @Devin There's an option to retract your closed vote if you click on the "close" link

Comment: aaah @nightning, always so helpful, never noticed that, thank you!

Comment: i find it to be a relevant question. before displaying/hiding any information, one has to think about the experience. 

showing credit details is always tricky, especially if one is using assets from creative commons, where attribution is required. 

(now that i have said that, i guess the question now requires some edit)

Comment: i am new here, so if any of you can edit the question better, please go ahead! i may still be missing the larger point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be weighed on how much exposure you are trying to generate. If the goal is to provide proof that you were the one that produced the website and/or hopefully pull some of that companies clients to you as potential future customers, then that is definitely one way to do it.

If you're looking for a more discrete way of signing your work, i'd suggest using a [humans.txt](http://humanstxt.org/) file.

Comment: Thanks! This is great. Didn't know about this.